# React Native - Multiple navigators (drawer and bottom tab on same page)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

AppNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createSwitchNavigator,createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';
import AuthLoadingScreen from '../screens/AuthLoadingScreen'
import Login from '../screens/Login';
import SideBarNavigator from './SideBarNavigator'


export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen ,
    App: MainTabNavigator,
    Auth: Login,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

MainTabNavigator.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator,createDrawerNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';
import SideBarNavigator from './SideBarNavigator';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  ),
};

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator({
  Links: LinksScreen,
});

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Links',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-link' : 'md-link'}
    />
  ),
};

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});


SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-options' : 'md-options'}
    />
  ),
};



export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LinksStack,
  SettingsStack,
}
```

);

SideBarNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator,createDrawerNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';

const HomeStacks = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStacks.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  ),
};

const LinksStacks = createStackNavigator({
  Links: LinksScreen,
});

LinksStacks.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Links',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-link' : 'md-link'}
    />
  ),
};

const SettingsStacks = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});


SettingsStacks.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-options' : 'md-options'}
    />
  ),
};



export default createDrawerNavigator({
  HomeStacks,
  LinksStacks,
  SettingsStacks,
});
```

What I want to do is have both the Drawer (SideBar.js) and the TabNav (MainNav.js) to be on the same page.

So it would look like GoogleMaps on android, on the initial page. Where you can access both the Drawer Side Bar and the bottom three links.

How do I achieve something like that?

I tried to mess around with MainTabNavigator, but I can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your Drawer Navigator as your `MainNavigator` in your `SwitchNavigator` and wrap `TabNavigator` inside `MainNavigator` as your `initialRoute` and have a custom component for your drawer if you don't wish to show Home as a clickable link for your tabs inside the drawer.

The code should look like the below:

```
export default createSwitchNavigator({
   AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen ,
   App: MainNavigator,
   Auth: Login,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
});
```

Your `MainNavigator` then should be a drawer if you want to welcome your user on the tabs with drawer with them as whole.

```
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
   Home: { screen: MyTabs},
   Notifications: { screen: MyNotificationsScreen }
}, {
   contentComponent: props =>  <MyCoolCustomDrawerComponent {...props} /> //optional
});
```

and, finally `MyTabs` should be your TabNavigator.

This way you can achieve what you want.

**Note: In order to nest the navigators this way, please declare and define your TabNavigator before DrawerNavigator and DrawerNavigator before SwitchNavigator.**